# RMarkdown cache leads to Latex error when knitting to PDF

Tags: pdf, caching, latex, r-markdown

I'm getting a weird error that I can't seem to understand. I have an rMarkdown file with a mixture of code, tables, and plain text (in RStudio).

I want to knit to PDF. I am able to do this, **but only if I've deleted the cache folder**. If the cache has been created, I get the following error when trying to do subsequent knits:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

This is especially confusing as it always works the first time, and the PDF output looks exactly as I want it to. My code components are set to "cache=TRUE", because it's a big file and I want to cut down on loading time. I've looked up what that error means, but I can't find anything on how it relates to the cache.

If it's of any use, this is my header:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 4
    number_sections: no
    fig_caption: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Helvetica
font-family: Helvetica Neue
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: left=35mm, right=20mm, top=30mm, bottom=30mm
bibliography: resources/refs.bib
csl: resources/apa.csl
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}                           # Latex package for formatting PDFs.
- \pagestyle{fancy}                               # Set page style.
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}            # Thickness of header line.
- \setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}             # Ensures consistent space between header line and text.
- \renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}  # Show URLs in footnote.
---
```

I can't directly share my data, but the setup for one of my tables looks like this:

```
exp2_age_gender_table %>%
  kable("latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
  column_spec(2, italic = TRUE) %>%
  column_spec(4, italic = TRUE) %>%
  row_spec(5, bold = TRUE)
```

The list of files contained in the created cache folder:

```
load-packages_0e5c21f97bd6e3c6091073c85b87d490.rdb
__packages
exp2-age-gend-table_009cc9300f71eb94b8251a5ed005e883.RData
exp2-age-gend-table_009cc9300f71eb94b8251a5ed005e883.rdb
exp2-age-gend-table_009cc9300f71eb94b8251a5ed005e883.rdx
exp2-age-gend-table-data_fc15cdaa97d5a922fc695858c44a93ac.RData
exp2-age-gend-table-data_fc15cdaa97d5a922fc695858c44a93ac.rdb
exp2-age-gend-table-data_fc15cdaa97d5a922fc695858c44a93ac.rdx
load-packages_0e5c21f97bd6e3c6091073c85b87d490.RData
load-packages_0e5c21f97bd6e3c6091073c85b87d490.rdx
raw-data_d44409d75a5aed8718bc355ff7b167fc.RData
raw-data_d44409d75a5aed8718bc355ff7b167fc.rdb
raw-data_d44409d75a5aed8718bc355ff7b167fc.rdx
```

Comment: If I set "cache=FALSE" on all of my code components, the PDF knits fine every time...

Comment: So did `cache=FALSE` solve your issue?

Comment: I wouldn't say it solved it, as I actually wanted to use the cache, not avoid it entirely. Though I managed to get this working by: 1) putting my code components back to "cache=TRUE', 2) deleting the cache folder, 3) hard resetting R studio and running the code from scratch. Weird RStudio glitch.